# Problem in downloading twitter search pages

Tags: c++, twitter, wininet

I am trying a small program to download webpages and collect some data.
The program works fine for most webpages. However, there is problem in downloading Twitter search results.
The download program seems to get only twitter homepage. I am using WinInet for downloading.

Noticed Twitter uses "#!" in its url. (www.twitter.com/#!/...). Is it something to do with this?

Appreciate any suggestion on how to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged "C++"? Sounds like the perfect job for wget + bash scripting, or maybe Perl and Perl::curl...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect some data from Twitter you should use their [API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am coming across these hashbang in more pages recently. Even  normal Google search page seems to have hashbang. Is there some specific ways to download these pages? Are there any download libraries available to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the hashbang and it will be fine. However, using the API is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably falling victim to the cache, especially with # in the URL. Try INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE (ignore cache and reload from network | do not bother writing response to cache) for dwFlags in HttpOpenRequest or InternetOpenURL. 
You could also try URLEncoding the #.